# Git / Windows - How do I stop git from following symbolic links?

Tags: git

I'm trying to find a way to disable git from following symbolic links on Windows 7 while adding/committing files the repo. I've tried setting config.symlinks to false (`git config --bool core.symlinks false`). Is there a simple solution to disable this behavior?

Comment: which git are you using? Cygwin or another one?

Comment: @Ronald Currently using Cygwin. Git version 1.7.4.mysysgit.0

Comment: msysgit isn't the Cygwin version - it's the MSYS version (MSYS is the fork of Cygwin that ships with MinGW). AFAIK, there's no switch to turn following symlinks off, but IIRC Cygwin symlinks != Windows symlinks, so you might be able to play with that..

Comment: @adymitruk I'm linking to a folder that contains all of our client side libraries. It provides instant access to our plugins/libs/etc in dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't easily do that on windows. However, you can simply modify your .git/info/exclude file to exclude this folder. It's more a workaround, but as you're using only one folder, it will work well (I've been using that for build folder, which I don't want to pollute my git status)

Comment: I can't get this to work. Have have cloned a repository that has a dummy file (named src): `/path/src`. On Windows I have created a symbolic link: `mklink -d /path/src /otherplace/src` (but I of course had to delete the dummy src file first). In both my .gitignore and .git/info/exclude I have `/path/src/` and `/path/src` but I still get: `error: readlink("path/src"): Function not implemented
error: unable to index file path/src
fatal: updating files failed` any ideas?