# How to get Git on Windows to ignore symbolic links

Tags: windows, git, symlink, gitignore

I can't get this to work.

I have cloned a repository that has a dummy file (named src): `/path/src`.

On Windows I have created a symbolic link: `mklink -d /path/src /otherplace/src` (but I of course had to delete the dummy src file first).
In both my `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` I have

```
/path/src/ 
/path/src 
path/src/
path/src
```

And I have tried

```
git ls-files -s | gawk '/120000/{print $4}'

git update-index path/src/ --assume-unchanged
```

but I still get:

```
error: readlink("path/src"): Function not implemented
error: unable to index file path/src   
fatal: updating files failed
```

I have tried all [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511312/ignore-symbolic-links-in-gitignore) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662868/what-happens-when-i-clone-a-repository-with-symlinks-on-windows) [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556144/git-windows-how-do-i-stop-git-from-following-symbolic-links). And even [this doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symlinks-in-windows).
Any ideas?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Jus12, honestly I don't remember if I ever solved it. It was some time ago, and I don't remember which project it was.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I know setting `git config core.symlinks true` instead of `git config core.symlinks false` got rid of the Function not implemented error for me.

Consequently, the symlinks I created using mklink in Windows were pushed without error, but when cloning the project again, the symlinks become text files that says where the original files are located instead of working as a real symlink.

Comment: `git config core.symlinks true` works for me!

Answer (score 3):

You can do a checkout ignoring this single file like this:

```
git checkout HEAD . --no path/src
```

The `.gitignore` file only works for adding stuff to the index. Even a modifications on files commited before adding it to the `.gitignore` are not ignored.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a command for "git checkout HEAD . --no" "error: Ambiguous option: no" (Git 1.9.4)

Comment: Yes @JoeyC it happened just now when I tested it. Will look for another solution.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late, but I ran into this issue.

In my case, I apparently had checked in my symlink at some point.  So no matter what I did, `.gitignore` would not work (I think that is what Alexandre was getting at).

**REPAIR:**

1. Remove all symlinks
2. See if git now thinks there are deleted files to commit.
3. If so, then go ahead and commit the deletions.

Now you can re-add your symlinks and `.gitignore` should work.

Comment: Thanks it was more simple and easy than other steps !

Answer (score 1):

Here are my steps for this issue, similar, but a bit different from other answers.

Let's say I had a folder `.fvm` contain `file.json` and `flutter_sdk(link)` that all commited in git before, then I want to ignore out `flutter_sdk`.

1. Add `.fvm/flutter_sdk` and `.fvm/flutter_sdk/` in `.gitignore`.
2. Cut `.fvm/flutter_sdk` out to other place than the repository.
3. `git add .` and `git commit ....`
4. Paste back the link.